# If your donation is matched, do you get reward for the match as well?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, reward-punishment

If an organization has a philanthropist that agreed to match every dollar donated.

If you give $100, and he matches your $100. Do you get reward for $200 or $100?

Had you not given your $100, neither would he...(unless some else donated $100)

Comment: יִתֵּן וְיִתְּנוּ אֲחֵרִים - חָסִיד.

Comment: Why might you think that your reward is directly correlated to dollars? If you do something good, you get an unknown amount of credit (probably proportional to the effort you put in (Avot 5:25), probably also weighted by the exact Mitzva). If you cause someone else to do something good, that's good, in which case, see above.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/113419/170

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to have to step WAY back, because this answer depends on adjusting one of the assumptions behind the question and ask you to visit [the answer I gave to "Weighing mitzvot/aveirot"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66346/1570).

I wrote "Yishmael was repaid in terms of 'ba'asher hu sham -- as he was there'. The way your soul stands at that moment is the direct cause of reward or punishment." And "The greater the effort and sacrifice, the bigger the change in "ba'asher hu sham -- as you are there", when being judged."

So it depends on how the matching funds change your experience, which in turn shapes the act's impact on your soul.

As the mishnah puts it, "be [as] aware of a "light" mitzvah as with a weighty one, for you don't know the reward for [each of the] mitzvos." (Avos 2:1)

Comment: I moved the bulk of my answer to where it was more appropriate, leaving the application to this case here.